# Is it prejudicial to introduce a child to a new environment soon after a separation?

Tags: development, social-development

Are there any studies showing how the reactions of a children (ages 2-4) are to new environments right after their parents separation?

How soon would it be "too soon" for the introduction of a new stable environment that includes another parental figure? Time, stability and love are key points on the adaptation process, I am aware of that. But would it be prejudicial to include a different, stable relation to that process?

Answer (score 2):

I can say that a child needs attention to get him stabilized before giving him a completely new environment.

I assume that the child spends most of his time with parents who shower him with eternal love. After the separation I don't think it is easy to change to a new environment while dealing with seeing a parent far less often.

As a 2-4 year child, he doesn't know what is happening around him. It is better to introduce your new environment in a way that makes it fun.  Also, don't do it all at once; do it stage by stage.

Take time to introduce your new partner to your child. Let your new partner interact with your child and fill the gap which is left by the other parent's absence. Once the new partner establishes credibility and attains the love of your child he will force you to do what your are expecting.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  I've made some edits to try and clarify your answer.  Please feel free to review my edits to make sure I got your intention right, and fix anything I got wrong by making further edits.

Comment: _"he will force you..."_ -- could you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: by means of "he will force you.." i meant that once the new relation get the credibility from the child the child's expectation towards the relation will increase exponentially in all ways.. which intern give him a thought to think the new relationship as a replacement to his mother and leads to the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

Im a single parent of youngsters. Each is quite different and has different needs concerning custody stuff and promoting/maintaining their relationship with their mom.

Your dilemma warrants the help of a expert that can give specific feedback about your specific and unique child. The correct answer is not a quick one.

I was awarded custody of my son when he was almost five. With in months he was developing a relationship with a psychologist that help him and also helped me. The neat thing is that years later we see see the same doc (when need), he has the expertise, but also the relationship and knowledge about my boy.

My daughter is completely different, how she problems solve and her needs. The stuff I learned for my son does not directly translate to the daughter. What worked in my family isn't necessarily what will work for yours, but having gone through the separation bit with young kids, I strongly recommend that you chase down some parenting intervention for a quality mental health professional with child development expertise.

Good Luck!